# Source directory not set (-s)

Tags: linux, git, bash

I installed ttree in bash on ubuntu on windows for the first time and after installing it I am getting this error:

```
Source directory not set (-s)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Don't know what is the big deal about this. But shouldn't it be as simple as `ttree -s "/path/to/source/dir"`. Just a wild guess though..

Comment: actually i have found the answer,   it should be like ttree -s sourcefile -d destinationfile

Comment: Hmm. Great.. You can post it here or may delete the question :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have found the answer, it should be like

```
ttree -s sourcefile -d destinationfile –-
```